# ERR_UNKNOWN_RL_SCHEME whatsapp link

Tags: flutter, dart, whatsapp

im trying to link whatsapp with this function, i already try many url options but nothing works

```
    static Future launchThisUrl(url) async {
    Uri dataUrl = Uri.parse(url!);

    if (await canLaunchUrl(dataUrl)) {
      await launchUrl(dataUrl);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $dataUrl';
    }
  }

  static launchWhatsApp(
      {required String phone, required String message}) async {
    String url = '';
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      url = "https://wa.me/$phone?text=${Uri.parse(message)}";
      log('ANDROID == $url');
    } else {
      log('IOS');
      url = "https://wa.me/send?phone=$phone&text=${Uri.parse(message)}";
    }
    await launchThisUrl(url);
  }
```

but it always return this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url in my case that works, looks like this. Try this:

```
https://wa.me/${phone}/?text=hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:

```
import 'package:whatsapp_unilink/whatsapp_unilink.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

        final link = WhatsAppUnilink(
          phoneNumber: '+000000000',
          text: "hello",
        );
    
        await launch('$link');
```